# Validation in Domain Model of Domain Service?

Tags: validation, domain-driven-design

I'm reading the book "Architecting Applications for the Enterpise (Dino Esposito)". It raised a question about validation.

The Domain Model can have a property CanBeSaved which calls the Validate() method of the Domain Model. All good, except for complex situations.
For example a Customer model which needs a unique customer code (ex. 000542). You can only check this with database access. Isn't it better to put the Validation always in a Domain Service. So you have only one way of checking if an aggregate is in a valid state? If you use both, a developer can 'forget' to use the domain service validation for the Customer.

Comment: When you mention Domain Services you actually mean Application Services. Domain Services no nothing about databases or external  infrastructure.

If you want to put external validation logic into the application service, this might be a practical way to go. I don't completely understand your statement about developers who "forget to use validation". If your application service is the only way to create an aggregate, how can anyone "forget" doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find it better to have [always valid](http://codebetter.com/gregyoung/2009/05/22/always-valid/) entities rather than rely on an external validation object.

That being said, unique checks are a bit of an exception since it is often not something that the aggregate itself can determine on its own, you have to look into all existing aggregates to see if the value is not already taken. What I do is  check for availability of the value before creating the entity, and also put a constraint in the database which will verify uniqueness at persistence time. You could also try to find a domain concept that encompasses all your entities and make it an aggregate that has a list of all codes and enforces the uniqueness invariant.

Comment: Check the availability before is a good, IF you always do it. Your UI can prefill it with a new unique value.The problem is the same with identity card number, bank account numbers, social security numbers, ...

Comment: Sure. Unique checks are a pretty open question in DDD. If you really want it to be immediately consistent at all times, you should definitely try to find an overarching concept and make it an aggregate that verifies uniqueness of all `Customer` `codes`. Changes in  `codes` and `Customer` creations should all go through that aggregate. If eventual consistency is an option, you could also have an application service that subscribes to a `CustomerCreated` event and takes a compensating action if it detects a `code` collision. But that would mean letting go of the unique constraint in the database

Comment: *"The problem is the same with ..."* - beware of blanket statements that seem common sense. There's often a lot to be found if you talk things trough with your domain expert. There might actually be cases in your domain where you need two of these things with identical values at the same time.